# Convergence of non increasing and non decreasing sequences to the same limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $a_n$ is a non decreasing sequence and $b_n$ is a non increasing sequence, and $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$, this is this sufficient condition for concluding that they both converge to the same limit.

If no, what else is needed?

Comment: $a_n = 1, b_n = 2$ is a counter-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given conditions only imply that $a_n$ and $b_n$ both converge. Their limits may not be equal. For example take $a_n=1-\frac 1 n$ and $b_n =2+\frac  1 n$. If you also know that $b_n-a_n \to 0$ you can conclude that the limts are equal.

Comment: Martin' example is simpler but I tried to construct strictly monotonic sequences.

Comment: This does not deserve another question. I am trying to show $b_n - a_n = \frac{1}{n} \left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n \to 0$ without knowing beforehand that $\lim \left (1 + \frac{1}{n}\right )^n = e$. I like to use the product rule so that $\lim \frac{1}{n} \lim \left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n = 0 * \lim \left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n = 0 $. But using product rule requires first showing $\lim \left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n$ is bounded from above. How best to show the boundedness? Thanks.

Comment: Use the fact that $1+x\leq e^{x}$.